# Simple MySQL INSERT error

Tags: mysql

No doubt I'm missing something really simple here but I just can't see the problem with this query which is producing the following error:

```
SQL query:

INSERT INTO ads(
    ad_id, author, ad_date, category, title,
    description, condition, price, fullname,
    telephone, email, status, photo, photothumb
)
VALUES (
    NULL , 'justal', '1225790938', 'Windsurf Boards',
    'test', 'test', 'Excellent', '12', 'test',
    'test', 'test', '', '', ''
);

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near ''ad_id', 'author',
'ad_date', 'category', 'title', 'description',
'condition', '' at line 1
```

Can someone with a fresh pair of eyes spot the problem?

Thanks,
Al.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't you use back ticks instead of single quotes in column names?

```
INSERT INTO ads( `ad_id`, `author`, `ad_date`, `category`, `title`, `description`, `condition`, `price`, `fullname`, `telephone`, `email`, `status`, `photo`, `photothumb` )
VALUES (
NULL , 'justal', '1225790938', 'Windsurf Boards', 'test', 'test', 'Excellent', '12', 'test', 'test', 'test', '', '', ''
);
```

Comment: Yes, but not using quotes at all is eassier to read (and if your column names are such that you need to quote them, you chose the wrong column names)

Comment: i completely disagree. using backticks at all times is great for readability and saves you having to make up arbitrary names for fields when the perfect name would be "key", "value", etc.

Comment: and *I* agree with Alexander! :-p

Comment: I agree with you two. :p

Comment: backticks seems to have fixed the issue so maybe one of the column names (possibly status or condition) did need them? ;)

Comment: It's `condition`, see the answer from @gusmos

Answer (score 2):

It might be that CONDITION is a mysql keyword, and not allowed as column name.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-conditions.html

You definitely do not need the ' or `

Comment: if you had a column name of "condition" and it was a reserved keyword, wouldn't that mean you definitely DO need the backtick?

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes are used for string literals. In MySQL, by default, double quotes are also used for string literals although this is incompatible with standard SQL and you should stick to single quotes in your code.

For column names, you normally wouldn't quote them at all. If you need to - and you don't for any of yours - then quote them with a backquote (`), or set it to strict ANSI compatible mode (ANSI_QUOTES) and use double quotes.